# Executing java class in correct directory

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I cannot seem to run my java program because it thinks my MO.class file is in the classpath for my gson library. What am I doing wrong?

$ ls
gson  MO.java

$ javac -cp .:gson/gson/target/gson-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar MO.java

$ java -cp .:gson/gson/target/gson-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar MO
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MO (wrong name: com/google/gson/MO)**
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Comment: Remove the line `package com.google.gson;` from your file `MO.java`. Also, you need to compile your program before you can run it. It looks like you didn't, since there is no file `MO.class` in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the `package com.google.gson` from my MO.java file.